# Geodesics on the helicoid

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces, geodesic

The problem is as follows:

> Suppose that a geodesic $\alpha$ is intersecting a ruling of the
>   helicoid S given by $$x(u,v) = (u \cos(v),u \sin(v), v) $$ at a point $p$.
>   The angle at $p$ between the ruling and $\alpha$ is $\theta \in (0,
>  \pi/2)$. Furthermore, $p$ does not lie on the z axis and we call the
>   relative distance $\delta > 0$.
>
> (a) Show that $\delta > \cot(\theta)$
>
> (b) Show that if $\delta < \cot(\theta)$, then $\delta$ does not
>   intersect the $z$-axis
>
> (c) Find the geodesics for $\delta = \cot(\theta )$

I'm struggling with figuring out how to start on this. I don't understand how can I express the angle $\theta$ and the distance $\delta$. If you could help me explain that, I think I would be able to continue on my own.

Any help appreciated!

P.S.: This question is slightly connected to [Geodesics of Helicoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3254265/geodesics-of-helicoid) , the results obtained there might be useful in this problem as well.